# windows 7 - reading serial port parameters

Tags: serial-port, com

Let's assume that I run a program which reads/writes to a serial port (com). I known that the program uses baud rate 19200 and dynamically sets parity bit (mark parity or space parity). Device manager (port settings) for that port shows different values (baud rate 9600, parity none).

How can I check a real settings for that port ?

Answer (score 2):

In the command line try:

> mode com3

Instead of `com3` - enter the comport name of the port in interest. This command produces an output like:

```
Status for device COM3:

    Baud:            115200
    Parity:          None
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       2
    Timeout:         OFF
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     OFF
    RTS circuit:     OFF
```

Comment: The program uses COM3. I get following message: Device COM3 is not currently available.

Comment: That's probably because some other program is accessing the port. Close other programs and try again. It works for me.